# jQuery Promise callback with Parameters

Tags: ajax, promise, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how I could pass the parameters to the callback function triggered by jQuery's promise object. My method, which calls the ajax and then the promise methods looks like this:

```
var formObject = {
    call : function(thisForm, thisUrl, thisArray, thisCallback) {
        "use strict";
        var thisMethod = thisForm.attr('method').toUpperCase();
        var thisPromise = $.ajax({
            type : thisMethod,
            url : thisUrl,
            dataType : 'json',
            data : thisArray,
            cache : false
        });
        thisPromise.done(thisCallback(data, textStatus, jqXHR));
        thisPromise.fail(formObject.topError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown));
    }
};
```

The parameters in done() and fail() methods are incorrect - but this is exactly what I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to supply additional closures - the lines below should work fine:

```
thisPromise.done(thisCallback);
thisPromise.fail(formObject.topError.bind(formObject));
```

The `done` callback will be passed the `data, textStatus, jqXHR` parameters as supplied by `$.ajax`.  This line is just registering the supplied callback function directly.

The `fail` callback will similarly get the right parameters, except that I've used [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) here to ensure that `this` is correctly set to the `formObject`.  If this code is to be used on pre-ES5 browsers, just install a shim for `.bind` - there's one on the Mozilla site linked above.

Comment: @SpencerMark yes, that one should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

try to write instead

```
thisPromise.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
    thisCallback(data, textStatus, jqXHR); 
});
thisPromise.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
     formObject.topError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown); 
});
```

wrapping both the callbacks inside a function

Comment: @alnitak, premising that I don't know nothing about `thisCallback` and `formObject.topError` existence... why it shouldn't work? If it's due to lack of parameters I've just updated my answer :)

Comment: yeah, it was the lack of parameters.  The parameters are given in the OPs code.  You should of course now notice that the supplied functions are being passed _exactly_ the same parameters as the callbacks...

Comment: Yep I noticed :) He could just pass the function identifier, but I wanted to show the user how to pass a function with parameters, no matters which they are (in this specific case is clearly redundant)

Comment: So what you're saying is that I can simply pass the method / function name without any parameters and these will be passed over to the callback?

Answer (score 1):

Use closures:

```
var formObject = {
    call : function(thisForm, thisUrl, thisArray, thisCallback) {
        "use strict";
        var thisMethod = thisForm.attr('method').toUpperCase();
        var thisPromise = $.ajax({
            type : thisMethod,
            url : thisUrl,
            dataType : 'json',
            data : thisArray,
            cache : false
        });
        thisPromise.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                 thisCallback(/* additional parameters*/)
        });
..........................
    }
};
```